# Angular Firebase database value of Id is showing undefined

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2

In Firebase database cart Id is showing undefined(check image) and only one category item added in Firebase database and when add another product not show in database but quantity is increased.

This is the shopping cart service.

please help me.

[image]

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireDatabase } from 'angularfire2/database';
import { Product } from './models/product';
//import 'rxjs/add/operator/take';
import { take } from 'rxjs/operators';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/take';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ShoppingCardService {


  constructor(private db: AngularFireDatabase) { }

  private create() {
    return this.db.list('/shopping-carts').push({
      dateCreated: new Date().getTime()
    });
  }
  private getCart(cartId: string) {
    return this.db.object('/shopping-carts/' + cartId);
  }

  private getItem(cartId: string, productId: string) {
    return this.db.object<any>('/shopping-carts/' + cartId + '/items/' + productId);
  }


  private async getOrCreateCartId() {
    let cartId = localStorage.getItem('cartId');
    if (cartId) return cartId;

    let result = await this.create();
    localStorage.setItem('cartId', result.key);
    return result.key;
  }


  async addToCart(product: Product) {
    let cartId = await this.getOrCreateCartId();
    let item$ = this.getItem(cartId, product.$key);

    item$.snapshotChanges().pipe(take(1)).subscribe((item: any) => {
      if (item.key != null) {
        item$.update({ quantity: (item.payload.val().quantity || 0) + 1 });
      }
      else {
        item$.set({ product: product, quantity: 1 });
      }
    });
  }
}
```

This is the product-card-component.ts ...
In product-card-component.ts used the addToCart() method.

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { Product } from '../models/product';
import { ShoppingCardService } from '../shopping-card.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-product-card',
  templateUrl: './product-card.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./product-card.component.css']
})
export class ProductCardComponent  {
  @Input('product') product: Product;
  @Input('show-actions') showActions = true;
  constructor(private cartService: ShoppingCardService) { }



  addToCart(product: Product) {
    this.cartService.addToCart(product);


  }

}
```

**model/product.ts**

```
export interface Product {
  $key: string;
  title: string;
  price: number;
  category: string;
  imageUrl: string;
}
```

Comment: A `productId` has an undefined value somewhere.  We can't see where that is, since we don't see a call to `addToCart` anywhere.  You're going to have to do some debugging to figure that out.

Comment: addToCart(product: Product) {
    this.cartService.addToCart(product);  }  This is the product-card-component.ts..

Comment: Yes, and what **exactly** did you pass to `addToCart`?

Comment: export interface Product {
  $key: string;
  title: string;
  price: number;
  category: string;
  imageUrl: string;
}

Comment: That looks like a data structure, not an exact value.

Comment: The value of ID (-KrqgOLs07ZkbapP4EGi) should show in place of undefined(check picture)?? value of id take from firebase.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue
so inside model/product.ts, I modified **$key** to **key**

```
    export interface Product {
      key: string;
      title: string;
      price: number;
      category: string;
      imageUrl: string;
    }
```

and added a **'/'** at the end in the getItem method call's path

```
        private getItem(cartId: string, productId: string) {
            return this.db.object('/shopping-carts/' + cartId + '/items/' + productId +'/');
     }
```

Worked with me!